# Inheritance of Attributes on Blocks

Tags: sysml

I have a parent block (call it Block 1), which has an attribute. Lets call it VoltageIn. The attribute remains empty on this block. 
The second block is a child of Block 1 (call it Block 2) and inherits the attribute VoltageIn. Here I want to give a value ( VoltageIn = 230V). 
The third block (Block 3) is a child of Block 2 and therefore it inherits the attribute VoltageIn = 230V.

Now, my question is how to handle this with SysML?

Comment: Hi, this is handled in the same ways than UML (more help exist for it). But are you sure that your model contains three blocks or maybe they are instance of the same block type? VoltageIn = 230V means in UML or SysML that VoltageIn value equals '230V' so VoltageIn is a Attribute of type String?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to give attributes values, is to create instances of the blocks. Create an instance of Block 2 and assign the value of 230V to VoltageIn. When you then create needed instances of Block 3, it will inherit that value.

Another way of going about this is to assign a default value to VoltageIn of Block 2 to 230V. This is then passed to Block 3. Sometimes you don't want to deal with instances, so this is another option.

Comment: And when I I want to create a child of a child? Is it possible to create an Instance of the Instance?